# What's a good way to encourage a toddler to blow their nose?

Tags: toddler

My son refuses to blow his nose. Goo streams down his top lip, and he sniffs it up again if we don't catch it in time.

What's a good way to encourage a two-year-old to blow their nose into a tissue or handkerchief?

Comment: Great question!  +1 - wish I had an answer, I have yet to meet a toddler that ignores snot running down his/her face and only occasionally snuffles at it (or licks it off - I mean, eww!) and I have known **a lot** of toddlers/preschoolers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have three boys who all learned to blow their nose probably around 1 year old. They mostly learned from watching their mom who blows her nose around them very visibly and loudly. When they had snot in their nose, she'd hold a tissue to their nose and encourage then saying, "blow your nose." At first they'd do nothing or just make a noise and we'd mostly pinch the snot out. But they all eventually started to actually blow their nose.

Answer (score 0):

We used the snot bulb to suction our kid's snot-filled nose when she was a baby, and just never stopped.  She hated it, learned to blow her nose in self-defense before she was 2.

Answer (score -2):

Kids at that age love affection and other "treats"... putting out a realistic consequence as a result of the undesired behavior can be quite productive.

"Daddy, I want a hug."

"Oh, but you don't blow your nose properly.  Go wash your hands first."

Be consistent in your implementation and always make it a realistic consequence for the undesired behavior and they will adapt to get what they want faster -- e.g. he wants the hug more than he doesn't want to blow his nose.

Comment: But when they choose the other over your affection, how will that make you feel? I guess I am in the position where affection is given without strings attached. I agree with "realistic consequences" but not with encouraging conditional love.

Comment: Washing hands before giving a hug when you've been wiping your nose with your hands is bad?  If you think that and give a -1 for it, then IMO you have some room to grow as a parent.

Comment: And, btw, this technique *worked* for me as a parent and I have a very loving child who feels deeply cared for.